Is there option to split this string into right shape in Databricks using SQL?
One of my column's values looks like this:
<Header>Lineposition<TAB>AdditionalPosition<TAB>PositionView<TAB>MaterialNumber<TAB>Description<TAB>Quantity<TAB>ExtUnitCost<TAB>ExtUnitPrice<TAB>TransferPrice<TAB>ExtNetPrice<TAB>ExtNetPriceFC<TAB>Discount<TAB>LocalMargin<TAB>NetMargin<TAB>UnitPrice<TAB>PositionType<RET>1<TAB>False<TAB>001<TAB><TAB>Industrial System 24V 80A Parallel System<TAB>1<TAB>7304<TAB>18285<TAB>9720<TAB>12665<TAB>12665<TAB>0<TAB>23<TAB>42<TAB>12665<TAB>Normal<RET>1<TAB>True<TAB>001<TAB><TAB>Industrial System 24V 80A Parallel System<TAB>1<TAB>7304<TAB>18285<TAB>9720<TAB>12665<TAB>12665<TAB>0<TAB>23<TAB>42<TAB>12665<TAB>Normal<RET>2<TAB>False<TAB>001.1<TAB><TAB>Protect RCS 24 V / 2 x100 A<TAB>1<TAB>6118<TAB>15609<TAB>8333<TAB>10926<TAB>10926<TAB>30<TAB>24<TAB>44<TAB>10926<TAB>Normal<RET>2<TAB>True<TAB>001.1<TAB><TAB>Protect RCS 24 V / 2 x100 A<TAB>1<TAB>6118<TAB>15609<TAB>8333<TAB>10926<TAB>10926<TAB><TAB>24<TAB>45<TAB>10926<TAB>Normal<RET>3<TAB>False<TAB>001.2<TAB><TAB>Documentation<TAB>1<TAB>196<TAB>500<TAB>267<TAB>325<TAB>325<TAB>35<TAB>18<TAB>40<TAB>325<TAB>Normal<RET>3<TAB>True<TAB>001.2<TAB><TAB>Documentation<TAB>1<TAB>196<TAB>500<TAB>267<TAB>325<TAB>325<TAB><TAB>18<TAB>47<TAB>325<TAB>Normal<RET>4<TAB>False<TAB>001.3<TAB><TAB>Packing<TAB>1<TAB>540<TAB>1028<TAB>670<TAB>668<TAB>668<TAB>35<TAB>0<TAB>19<TAB>668<TAB>Normal<RET>4<TAB>True<TAB>001.3<TAB><TAB>Packing<TAB>1<TAB>540<TAB>1028<TAB>670<TAB>668<TAB>668<TAB><TAB>0<TAB>47<TAB>668<TAB>Normal<RET>5<TAB>False<TAB>001.4<TAB><TAB>Factory Acceptance Testing<TAB>1<TAB>450<TAB>1148<TAB>450<TAB>746<TAB>746<TAB>35<TAB>40<TAB>40<TAB>746<TAB>Normal<RET>5<TAB>True<TAB>001.4<TAB><TAB>Factory Acceptance Testing<TAB>1<TAB>450<TAB>1148<TAB>450<TAB>746<TAB>746<TAB><TAB>40<TAB>61<TAB>746<TAB>Normal<RET>

It's packed into 1 row string while it should be a list of materials with all of the details.
Each row has a different size of elements in that string that could be easily transformed into the right shape.
I have tried
WHEN size(SPLIT(SPLIT(QuoteOverview, '<RET>')[0], '<TAB>')) >= 1 AND t.row_num > 1 THEN SPLIT(SPLIT(QuoteOverview, '<RET>')[0], '<TAB>')[0] 

For each of the elements but of course, this one doesn't make new rows with right values and also does not put right information in specific columns.
Based on the top view expected output is more or less this:
Lineposition    AdditionalPosition  PositionView    MaterialNumber  Description Quantity    ExtUnitCost CostReduction   ReducedCost ExtUnitPrice    TransferPrice   ExtNetPrice ExtNetPriceFC   Discount    LocalMargin NetMargin   UnitPrice   PositionType
1   False   001     Industrial System 24V 80A Parallel System   1   7304    0   7304    18285   9720    12665   12665   0   23  42  12665   Normal
1   True    001     Industrial System 24V 80A Parallel System   1   7304    0   7304    18285   9720    12665   12665   0   23  42  12665   Normal
1   False   001.1       Protect RCS 24 V / 2 x100 A 1   6118    0   6118    15609   8333    10926   10926   30  24  44  10926   Normal


So you are trying to write an SQL query that reads one column, and fills other columns with the data. Am I right?

This is what need to be done, based on this column ( with  and  ) i need to build columns with values from it, no idea how. For each of row , number of elements are different ( for ID 1 can be 5 elements , for ID 2 can be 10 )
